# Failed to sent virtual key "Alt+Space" using "SendInput()" in C with GCC/Mingw32 Compiler?

Tags: c, winapi, console-application, mingw32, virtual-keyboard

I tried to pop up the menu using `Windows API`: [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but totally failed every time.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main (void)
{
    INPUT Alt_Space[4] = {0};

    Alt_Space[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  // Alt Key down
    Alt_Space[0].ki.wVk = VK_MENU;

    Alt_Space[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  // Space Key down
    Alt_Space[1].ki.wVk = VK_SPACE;

    Alt_Space[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  // Space Key up
    Alt_Space[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    Alt_Space[2].ki.wVk = VK_SPACE;

    Alt_Space[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  // Alt Key up
    Alt_Space[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    Alt_Space[3].ki.wVk = VK_MENU;

    SendInput ( 4, Alt_Space, sizeof(INPUT));

    system ("pause");
}
```

Can anyone know why this code failed to pop up the menu? Thanks.

Compile Command:

```
 mingw32-gcc.exe -O3 -c "Console.c" -o "Console.o"
 mingw32-gcc.exe -o "Console.exe" "Console.o"
```

Comment: No lack of simple explanations.  Won't work when the CTRL key is down.  Your program terminates a millisecond after it sent the keys to itself, bye bye menu.

Comment: @Hans Passant I edited my code, but still failed.

Comment: I could come up with more reasons but that's rather pointless.  What is this code supposed to do?  Why does the user need help accessing the system menu of your console window?  He already knows how to do that.

Comment: @Hans Passant What I want to do is pop up "Console Windows Properties": <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> -> <kbd>Up</kbd> -> <kbd>Up</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @Hans Passant I found the solution, and I answered my own question.

Comment: Incidentally, on my system, you wouldn't open the console window properties, but rather invoke the *Defaults* menu command. I'd not be happy to see that happen.

Comment: @IInspectable So sorry for that, I didn't paste the complete then. I edited my code below. If this code doesn't work on your computer, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I didn't use `SendInput()`, `keybd_event()` works perfectly with GCC/Mingw32.

I answered my own question, and leave it in order to provide some idea to whom have the same problem.

```
// Event
#define KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN 0x0000

// ALT + SPACE
#define SCAN_CODE_ALT     0x38
#define SCAN_CODE_SPACE   0x39
keybd_event ( VK_MENU  , SCAN_CODE_ALT  , KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event ( VK_SPACE , SCAN_CODE_SPACE, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event ( VK_SPACE , SCAN_CODE_SPACE, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP  , 0);
keybd_event ( VK_MENU  , SCAN_CODE_ALT  , KEYEVENTF_KEYUP  , 0);

// UP * 2
#define SCAN_CODE_UP      0x48
keybd_event ( VK_UP    , SCAN_CODE_UP   , KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event ( VK_UP    , SCAN_CODE_UP   , KEYEVENTF_KEYUP  , 0);
keybd_event ( VK_UP    , SCAN_CODE_UP   , KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event ( VK_UP    , SCAN_CODE_UP   , KEYEVENTF_KEYUP  , 0);

// Enter
#define SCAN_CODE_ENTER   0x1C
keybd_event ( VK_RETURN, SCAN_CODE_ENTER, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP  , 0);
keybd_event ( VK_RETURN, SCAN_CODE_ENTER, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
```

Comment: or without #define:

`keybd_event(VK_MENU,MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU,0),0,0)
keybd_event(VK_SPACE,MapVirtualKey(VK_SPACE,0),0,0)
keybd_event(VK_SPACE,MapVirtualKey(VK_SPACE,0),KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)
keybd_event(VK_MENU,MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU,0),KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)`